# How to change button text with a character?

Tags: java, android, button, character

I want to change button text with a character of a string which entered into a textview.I tried "settext" but faced with error.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    a=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String word=tv2.getText().toString();
    a.setText(word.charAt(3));
```

Comment: It's probably complaining about it being a char when expecting a string.

Comment: Just put `word.charAt(3)` in parenthesis and add cast to string: `a.setText(String.valueOf(word.charAt(3)));`

Comment: "Unfourtanetelly,app is stopped"
It may be a problem about settext, or character problem.I tried same code for changing button text with a string it worked.But this is not.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int). setText takes `CharSequence` . See  `public final void setText (CharSequence text)`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, solve it with NitroNbg's solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you said yourself, it wants a `String`. However, the `charAt()` returns a char, not a `String`.

To fix this, change `a.setText(word.charAt(3));` to `a.setText(String.valueOf(word.charAt(3)));`

This will convert the `char` outputted by `charAt()` into a `String`, which will then make it compatible for the text you are changing.

I hope this helps!